# Javascript Object has a property with two values

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I'm getting this strange behavior when overriding a property of my `Condition` Object by a value from a Form in Ionic 3. Its `value` is constructed as `null` and then overrided by a `String`. When I try to access it after overriding, I get `null` instead of `"8"`. Here is a picture of a `console.log` I ran:

[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORL1J.png)

This is how I'm trying to override the `value` property:

```
for (var property in form.value) {
  if (form.value.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
    var index = this.numberArray.findIndex((cond) => cond.name == property)
    this.numberArray[index].value = form.value[property];
  }
}
```

Comment: I see that you are using a non-strict equality == on your findIndex. Maybe try changing that to strict equality ===, also you should provide some data to go along with your loop

Comment: There is also not really a need for `findIndex` when you immediately just access the item by index in the array. You can use `find()` with the same iteree (with the exception of using strict equality as @Arrow mentioned)

Comment: Hey @Arrow! Thanks for the input. I tried changing to strict equality but it didn't change the outcome. What do you mean by providing some data to go along with the loop?

Comment: provide the  HTML form with the loop and the data working. from the console.log() it seems like some late evaluation. So you need to provide more context.

Comment: Hey, you were right @Arrow! Actually my (ngSubmit) was being called after the function that needed the data, so it was modifying it later. Thanks!

Comment: my pleasure :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use strict '===' and Looks like a late evaluation from your console.log()